# How to forward touch event from UITextField to UICollectionViewController / UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uicollectionview

I have a `cell` and on it a `UITextField`. TextField stretches **all over the cell**. When I press textField keyboard appears, but `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will not get called.

How can I trigger it? `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delivers the selected cell's `indexPath`. I need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd do it the other way around...

```
cell.textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do

```
MYTextFieldCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textfield becomeFirstResponder];
cell.textfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// code that needs the indexPath
```

subscribe to `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification` and set

```
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

when you're done

Answer (score 0):

First in forCellAtIndexPath method add tag to uitextfield

```
  UITextField *txtField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.width,self.view.height)];
     txtField.tag=indexPath.row;
txtField.delegate=self;
    [cell addSubview:txtField];
```

Second on textFieldDidBeginEditing
now you can get the indexpath of the cell by checking the tag of the textField

```
NSLog(@"IndexPath ....%li",(unsigned long)textField.tag);
```

Comment: what about `indexPath.section`, if not necessary I do not want to subclass `textField`